# Export each sql column to txt

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to export all my sql columns(name) from Table1 into a txt. the problem is that it exports only the first name from my sql.

Here is my code:

```
 string name;
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select membername from table1 ", con);
 SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

 while (read.Read())
 {
 name = (read["membername"].ToString());
 }
 read.Close();

 using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\fiscal.txt"))
 {
 sw.WriteLine("{0,-0}", name.ToString());
 sw.Close();
```

I think the problem is somewhere in my read.

Comment: You are looping over all the data but only keep the last value. *After* the loop finishes, you store the last value into the file

Comment: Do i guess that you are from greece?Thank you for your answer. How will i export all my columns?

Comment: by using the proper tool - SSIS or the Export Wizard. If you want to generate reports, the proper tool is SSRS. Why are you using client-side code for this?

Comment: Depending on your actual business requirements there are much better tools or libraries. SSIS is best for regular exports, file generation etc.  Eg, if the goal is to generate Excel files from a desktop or web application though, you can use EPPlus to generate a real `xlsx` file from a DataTable or collection of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the value in name is being overwritten each time it goes through the while loop. Change your code so that each value can be written.

```
 string name;
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select membername from table1 ", con);
 SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\fiscal.txt"))
 { 
 while (read.Read())
 {
 name = (read["membername"].ToString());
 sw.WriteLine("{0,-0}", name.ToString());
 }
 read.Close();
 sw.Close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over all the data but only keep the last value. After the loop finishes, you store the last value into the file. To fix this, you need to write the value *inside* the loop:

```
using(var con=new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    con.Open();
    var command = new SqlCommand("select membername from table1 ", con);
    using(var read = command.ExecuteReader())
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\fiscal.txt"))
    {
        while (read.Read())
        {
            var name = read["membername"]);
            sw.WriteLine("{0,-0}", name);
        }
    }
}
```

You should use `using` blocks instead of manually calling `Close()` to ensure that connections, files etc are disposed even if an exception is thrown.

Also note that you *don't* need to cast or convert to string in all places. `WriteLine` converts its value to string anyway.

Finaly note that `name` is declared and used in the innermost block. It's not needed anywhere else, so it *shouldn't* be declared outside that block.